# How to convert a `serde_json::Value ` to a `prost_types::Struct` in Rust?

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, serde, prost

```rust
fn to_struct(json: serde_json::Value) -> prost_types::Struct {
  // How to implement it?
}
```

Is there any crate to do it?

Comment: Some context: while you can treat `Value` as a serde deserializer, there's no serde support for prost_types https://github.com/tokio-rs/prost/issues/852 Also similar https://github.com/tokio-rs/prost/issues/541 (seems like they just don't use prost_types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://crates.io/crates/prost-wkt-types can generate `prost_wkt_types::Struct`, which supports `Deserialize` trait.

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily something you need a crate for. You do however have your types mixed: Not all `serde_json::Value`s can be converted to a `prost_type::Struct`, as `serde_json::Value`s can also be lists or strings or bools or numbers or null. If you do want to convert to a struct, you'll need to start from a `serde_json::Map`:

```
fn to_struct(json: serde_json::Map<String, serde_json::Value>) -> prost_types::Struct {
    prost_types::Struct {
        fields: json
            .into_iter()
            .map(|(k, v)| (k, serde_json_to_prost(v)))
            .collect(),
    }
}
```

Likely though, you only need the following

```
fn serde_json_to_prost(json: serde_json::Value) -> prost_types::Value {
    use prost_types::value::Kind::*;
    use serde_json::Value::*;
    prost_types::Value {
        kind: Some(match json {
            Null => NullValue(0 /* wat? */),
            Bool(v) => BoolValue(v),
            Number(n) => NumberValue(n.as_f64().expect("Non-f64-representable number")),
            String(s) => StringValue(s),
            Array(v) => ListValue(prost_types::ListValue {
                values: v.into_iter().map(serde_json_to_prost).collect(),
            }),
            Object(v) => StructValue(to_struct(v)),
        }),
    }
}
```

[Rustexplorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Aprost-types%20%3D%20%220.11.9%22%0Aserde_json%20%3D%20%221.0.96%22%0A*%2F%0A%0Afn%20to_struct(json%3A%20serde_json%3A%3AMap%3CString%2C%20serde_json%3A%3AValue%3E)%20-%3E%20prost_types%3A%3AStruct%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20prost_types%3A%3AStruct%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fields%3A%20json%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.into_iter()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.map(%7C(k%2C%20v)%7C%20(k%2C%20serde_json_to_prost(v)))%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.collect()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Afn%20serde_json_to_prost(json%3A%20serde_json%3A%3AValue)%20-%3E%20prost_types%3A%3AValue%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20use%20prost_types%3A%3Avalue%3A%3AKind%3A%3A*%3B%0A%20%20%20%20use%20serde_json%3A%3AValue%3A%3A*%3B%0A%20%20%20%20prost_types%3A%3AValue%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20kind%3A%20Some(match%20json%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Null%20%3D%3E%20NullValue(0%20%2F*%20wat%3F%20*%2F)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Bool(v)%20%3D%3E%20BoolValue(v)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Number(n)%20%3D%3E%20NumberValue(n.as_f64().expect(%22Non-f64-representable%20number%22))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20String(s)%20%3D%3E%20StringValue(s)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Array(v)%20%3D%3E%20ListValue(prost_types%3A%3AListValue%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20values%3A%20v.into_iter().map(serde_json_to_prost).collect()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object(v)%20%3D%3E%20StructValue(to_struct(v))%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20dbg!(to_struct(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20serde_json%3A%3Ajson!(%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22code%22%3A%20200%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22success%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22payload%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22features%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22serde%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22json%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.as_object()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.unwrap()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.clone()%0A%20%20%20%20))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A)

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto @Caesar's answer, I just wanted to show an example of how to go back and forth between `serde_json::Value` and `prost_types::Value`:

```rust
fn to_struct(json: serde_json::Map<String, serde_json::Value>) -> prost_types::Struct {
    prost_types::Struct {
        fields: json
            .into_iter()
            .map(|(k, v)| (k, serde_json_to_prost(v)))
            .collect(),
    }
}

fn serde_json_to_prost(json: serde_json::Value) -> prost_types::Value {
    use prost_types::value::Kind::*;
    use serde_json::Value::*;
    prost_types::Value {
        kind: Some(match json {
            Null => NullValue(0 /* wat? */),
            Bool(v) => BoolValue(v),
            Number(n) => NumberValue(n.as_f64().expect("Non-f64-representable number")),
            String(s) => StringValue(s),
            Array(v) => ListValue(prost_types::ListValue {
                values: v.into_iter().map(serde_json_to_prost).collect(),
            }),
            Object(v) => StructValue(to_struct(v)),
        }),
    }
}

fn prost_to_serde_json(x: prost_types::Value) -> serde_json::Value {
    use prost_types::value::Kind::*;
    use serde_json::Value::*;
    match x.kind {
        Some(x) => match x {
            NullValue(_) => Null,
            BoolValue(v) => Bool(v),
            NumberValue(n) => Number(serde_json::Number::from_f64(n).unwrap()),
            StringValue(s) => String(s),
            ListValue(lst) => Array(lst.values.into_iter().map(prost_to_serde_json).collect()),
            StructValue(v) => Object(
                v.fields
                    .into_iter()
                    .map(|(k, v)| (k, prost_to_serde_json(v)))
                    .collect(),
            ),
        },
        None => panic!("todo"),
    }
}
```